# Find column-count inbetween integers row-wise in matrix (matlab)

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a stupid problem, I can't find the answer to ^^.

I have a `100x10000 double matrix containing integers from 1 to 4` and want to find `row-wise` the `column-count between every single integer`

My first idea was to use:

```
storage_ones = cell(100,1); 

     for n = 1:100; 
       [row col] = find(matrix(n,:)==1);
       storage_ones{n,1} = col;
     end
```

And then substract them in another loop. But with `find` I get following Answer:

> Empty matrix: 1-by-0

Does anybody have an idea how I can solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You likely are suffering from floating point errors where `matrix` is never *exactly* equal to `1`. Instead look for where `matrix` is *close* to `1`: `abs(matrix(n, :)  - 1) < 1e-12`. If you matrix really only contains integers, consider using an integer datatype such as `uint8`

Comment: Also it's possible that you just don't have any 1's.

Comment: Did you try using the `histc` function? `[a, b] = histc(matrix', 1:4);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is potentially due to one of two things:

1. Since you're using a `double` datatype, it is possible that you're [encountering floating point errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686439/why-is-24-0000-not-equal-to-24-0000-in-matlab) where the values aren't going to be `1` *exactly*. If this is the case consider not checking for exact equality and instead check if it is very close to 1 using a small epsilon (here I used `1e-12`).

   ```
   [row, col] = find(abs(matrix(n,:) - 1) < 1e-12);
   ```

   If you really have an integer datatype, consider using `uint8` to store your data rather than `double` and then you can perform exact comparisons.

   ```
   matrix = uint8(matrix);

   % Then for your comparison
   find(matrix(n,:) == 1)
   ```
2. You may just not have any `1`'s in that column. If `find` can't find any matches, it returns an empty array.

   ```
   find([1 2 3] == 4)
   %   Empty matrix: 1-by-0
   ```

Comment: it was a floating point error, thanks! didnt think about this one :)